# Correct way to save oauth accounts in symfony

Tags: symfony, oauth

User can register on the site using oAuth or he can just link his oauth id to the existing account on site.

But I'm very doubt about the right way to store all possible oauth connections and link them to the user account in the db.

I thought about creating a table like this:

```
Table user_oauth_id
----------------------------------------------
user_id | facebook_id | google_id | twitter_id
----------------------------------------------
     1  |   blabla    |   blabla  |    blabla
```

Is it OK or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off with a user table, a user_oauth table and a one-to_many relation between them.

user_oauth would be like:

user_id oath_name oauth_id

Where oauth_name would be:  google, facebook etc.

Comment: Can you tell me about advantages of this method?

Comment: 1. Additional providers can be added without changing your database tables.  2. Easier to query one column than it is to query multiple column.  3.  Additional provider specific attributes (status, email etc) can be added.